# Keep event listeners alive after script completion in Node js

Tags: node.js

I have two .js file. One emits the event and another listens for it. The code looks as below.

**Emitter**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
utils.inherits(ConfigFileManager, EventEmitter);
var manager = new ConfigFileManager();
var watcher = chokidar.watch(CONFIG_DIR, {persistent: true});
watcher.on('add', function (path) {
    manager.emit('monitor', 'print this data');
});
watcher.on('change', function (path) {
    console.log('change event fired');
    manager.emit('monitor', 'print this data');
});
module.exports = manager;
```

The chokidar.watch keeps the event queue and restricts node from exiting. Now, listener is in different file, as given below.

**Listener**

```
var manager = require('./emitter');
manager.on('monitor', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and I run "node listener.js". The first time "add" event calls the listener, and all is fine. However when I change a file, the event is emitted, but the listener never gets it. If I add a setTimeout at the end of the listener.js, the listener is getting events until the timeout expires. So, once the listener script completes, the events are not received. How can I make the listener to listen forever?

Also, if I keep the listener code also in emitter.js, then it works, because chokidar.watch keeps the script from terminating. But, I want to keep them separate for better organization.

Comment: I know this is super old, but did you ever find a solution for this particular pattern?